# Polynomial division with modulo

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials

The following polynomials are in the field of whole numbers $mod$ $5$, so $x =5x$.

$f(x)=2+4x⁴+4x⁵+x⁶$

$g(x)=3+x+4x²+x³$

$f=q*g+r$

Is there a solution where the degree of $r$ is smaller than the degree of $g=3$? I would say no, because I would need at least multiply with $x³$ to get something with $x⁶$ but apparently there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Use the high-school algorithm for [polynomial long division with remainder.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division)

Alternatively, to compute the remainder use $\, x^3 \equiv -4x^2-x-3\pmod{g(x)}\,$ as a rewrite rule to reduce all powers $\,x^n\,$ until $\,n\le 2.$

Comment: Thank you, but why is $x^3≡−4x^2−x−3$? I know that I could write $g(x)$ as $g(x)-x^3=-4x^2-x-3$ but why is $g(x) mod 5 = 0$?

Comment: @jreuab $\ $ mod $g\!:\ 0\equiv g =  x^3\! + h\,\Rightarrow\, x^3\equiv -h\,$ so $\,x^4\equiv -xh,\ x^5\equiv -x^2h,\,\ldots\ $ where you recursively replace occurrences of $\,x^3,x^4\,$ when doing those multiplications.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that you need to multiply by $x^3$, but that is $q(x)$, not $r(x)$.
To solve this, try $q(x)=x^3+Ax^2+Bx+C$, $r(x)=Dx^2+Ex+F$.
Put them into the equation $f(x)=q(x)g(x)+r(x)$, and solve for $A,B,C,D,E,F$.  Start with the coefficients of $x^6$, then $x^5$, working down to the constant terms.
By the way, in mod $5$, $5x=0$ rather than $x$.

Comment: I tried your approach but it became soon to complicated to calculate. Anyway, thanks for your explaination!